# python pandas.read_csv date_parser cannot convert to datetime dtype

Tags: python, csv, datetime, timestamp

I was trying to read a .csv file in python as below:

*test.csv*

```
,date,stock
0,2018-01-01,600660.XSHG
1,2018-02-10,600276.XSHG
2,2018-05-18,600196.XSHG
```

by using:

```
dateCols = ['date']
dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') for d in dates]
a = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=dateCols, date_parser = dateparse)
```

I got

```
In: a.loc[0,'date']
Out:Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')
```

But what I hope to get is a `datetime` dtype, not a `Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dt.strftime if you need to convert datetime to other formats (but note that then dtype of column will be object (string)):

```
import pandas as pd

a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a.date)
a['date'] = a['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

it converts data column to mm/dd/yyyy type for example